# Go net/http server error: accept tcp [::]:443: accept4: too many open files; retrying

Tags: go, tcp, httpserver

Here is my server :

```
package main

import (
        "my-project/pkg/configuration"
        "my-project/pkg/logger"
        "my-project/pkg/server/appConfig"
        "my-project/pkg/server/handlers"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strings"
)

func main() {

        if len(os.Args) < 2 {
                logger.Log("error", "main", "Missing config.json file path as argument")
                return
        }

        configuration := configuration.Configuration{}
        appConfig.InitConfig(os.Args[1], &configuration)

        // download file
        http.HandleFunc("/file-download", handlers.DownloadFile(&configuration))

        // upload file
        http.HandleFunc("/file-upload", handlers.UploadFile(&configuration))

        // Get url
        http.HandleFunc("/file-url", handlers.GetUrl(&configuration))

        // Delete
        http.HandleFunc("/delete", handlers.DeleteHandler(&configuration))

        // file system
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(configuration.RootStoragePath))
        corsFS := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                if strings.HasSuffix(r.URL.Path, "/") {
                        http.NotFound(w, r)
                        return
                }
                w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })

        http.Handle("/", corsFS)

        err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "crt/server.crt", "crt/server.key", nil)
        if err != nil {
                logger.Log("error", "ListenAndServeTLS", err.Error())
        }
}
```

The server is under medium load.
The server crashed after a day of running,
I got the following error:

```
http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:443: accept4: too many open files; retrying
```

The command :

```
ls -ltr /proc/{PROCESS_ID}/fd
```

And the list of file, and socket:[XXXXXX] is growing all the time.
I don't want to change ulimit (1024), I don't think it is a long terme fix...

I don't really see where the problem could come from... In the handlers, I manipulate files but I take care to do defer Close()...
Do I have to set timeouts? If so where?

Thank you in advance for all the help ...

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find a solution.

The fact is that the `http.ListenAndServe` method of the `net/http` package has no timeout by default. This is voluntary from the Go team. So for a service in production, it is necessary to declare a `http.Server{}` and to configure it. [Go doc](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server).
Source : [Cloudflare blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/)

```
        srv := &http.Server{
                Addr:         ":443",
                ReadTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
                WriteTimeout: 120 * time.Second,
        }   
        srv.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)

        err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS("crt/server.crt", "crt/server.key")
```

`http.DefaultServeMux` is the default request multiplexer, and `HandleFunc` registers the handler function for the given pattern in the `DefaultServeMux`.
Here is the implementation :

```
func main() {

        if len(os.Args) < 2 { 
                logger.Log("error", "main", "Missing config.json file path as argument")
                return
        }

        configuration := configuration.Configuration{}
        appConfig.InitConfig(os.Args[1], &configuration)

        // download file
        http.HandleFunc("/file-download", handlers.DownloadFile(&configuration))

        // upload file
        http.HandleFunc("/file-upload", handlers.UploadFile(&configuration))

        // Get url
        http.HandleFunc("/file-url", handlers.GetUrl(&configuration))

        // Delete
        http.HandleFunc("/delete", handlers.DeleteHandler(&configuration))

        // file system
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(configuration.RootStoragePath))
        corsFS := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                if strings.HasSuffix(r.URL.Path, "/") {
                        http.NotFound(w, r)
                        return
                }   
                w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })

        http.Handle("/", corsFS)

        srv := &http.Server{
                Addr:         ":443",
                ReadTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
                WriteTimeout: 120 * time.Second,
        }   
        srv.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)

        err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS("crt/server.crt", "crt/server.key")
        if err != nil {
                logger.Log("error", "ListenAndServeTLS", err.Error())
                os.Exit(1)
        }
}
```

If you have any other advice, I'm obviously interested.